# Value of chronometer into string

Tags: java, android, string, chronometer

I'm trying to multiply the value of my chronometer or just try to get the value to be a string.

Every time I try to make it a string and use `toast.show()` to view it, my application crashes. I can get the value of my `EditText` to show up but I can't seem to get my chronometer to work.  Both the strings `time` and `fin` make it crash. Here's the code:

```
String hour = String.valueOf(mText.getText());
String time = String.valueOf(mChronometer.getBase() - stoppedMilliseconds);
int h = java.lang.Integer.parseInt(hour) / 60;
int t = java.lang.Integer.parseInt(time) * 1000 / 60;
int mm = h * t;
mon.setText(Integer.toString(mm));
String fin = "" + mm;


Toast.makeText(PoopActivity.this,
        "Money made: " + fin, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: when you say "crash" is there an exception? Perhaps you could post that exception?

Comment: No the application just freezes and stops working.

Answer (score 0):

There are several defects obscuring the function of this code.

- `time` is always negative.  Swap the subtraction arguments.
- When converting `hour` from hours to minutes, multiply rather than divide by 60.
- When converting `time` from milliseconds to minutes, divide rather than multiply by 1000.
- Computation of `mm` yields a quantity in minutes squared.  This can hardly have any meaning.
- Use `getApplicationContext` instead of `PoopActivity`.  Some application other than `PoopActivity` may be running.
- There is no exception handling.  For all we know, `mon` may be null and the `setText` throw an exception.  Wrap your code in a try - finally block:

`String fin = "";`

```
try
{
    // most of your code goes here

    mon.setText(Integer.toString(mm));
    String fin += mm;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // display the exception here if so inclined
}
finally
{
    Toast.makeText(PoopActivity.this,
    "Money made: " + fin, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

However, `fin` is a string containing a negative number just fine.